# JSON schema - validate sum of object properties

Tags: jsonschema

I have the following schema for a PUT network request body:

```
{
  title: "Character",
  description: "PUT character request body parameters",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    _id: {
      description:
        "ObjectID string for updating an existing character. Should not be present when a new character is created.",
      type: "string"
    },
    name: {
      description: "User input character name.",
      type: "string"
    },
    description: {
      description: "User input character description.",
      type: "string"
    },
    weaponId: {
      description: "ObjectID string for the equiped character weapon",
      type: "string"
    },
    armorId: {
      description: "ObjectID string for the equiped character weapon",
      type: "string"
    },
    shieldId: {
      description: "ObjectID string for the equiped character weapon",
      type: "string"
    },
    stats: {
      description: "Base character stats input by user",
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        str: {
          description: "Character strength stat.",
          type: "number",
          minimum: 100,
          maximum: 500
        },
        stam: {
          description: "Character stamina stat.",
          type: "number",
          minimum: 100,
          maximum: 500
        },
        wp: {
          description: "Character willpower stat.",
          type: "number",
          minimum: 100,
          maximum: 500
        },
        dex: {
          description: "Character dexterity stat.",
          type: "number",
          minimum: 100,
          maximum: 500
        },
        spd: {
          description: "Character speed stat.",
          type: "number",
          minimum: 100,
          maximum: 500
        }
      }
    }
  },
  required: ["name", "description", "stats"]
}
```

I would like to validate that the sum of the keys on the stats object does not exceed 1000. Is this possible with JSON schema - I did not find any mention of it in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: have you found a way to approach this? If yes, could you share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible with JSON Schema.

You will need to write your own business logic code to perform such calculations.